# I need to take specific strings with letters and numbers from one sheet to another and sort them by three letters and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, string, sorting

I need help with writing some VBA that will read selected cells, ask for what you want to sort (for example you input FTA) and then it will take those three letters and the numbers following the "-" and put them into another sheet in the correct column. I will be adding more and more of these strings to cells and be able to run this multiple times till i use up all of the letter/number combinations. I have some code right now that just takes me to sheet labeled piece count and highlights cell E1. My sheets are called "Tracking log" and "Piece list"

```
 Sub List()
    Dim xLStr As String, xStrTmp As String
    Dim xLStrLen As Long, xCount2 As Long, xCount As Long, I As Long, T As Long
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xArr
    Dim xArr2
    Dim xLnum As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xLStr = Application.InputBox("What is the string to list:", , , , , , , 2) 'creates aplication box
    If TypeName(xLStr) <> "String" Then Exit Sub '<> is not equal, "String" is the criteria
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'nessecary for faster running time
        xLStrLen = Len(xLStr) + Len(xLnum) 'sets string length to 7 in this case, len finds the length of a string
        For Each xCell In Selection 'searches in the highlighted cells
            xArr = Split(xCell.Value, xLStr) 'pulls the specific string that is to be searched
            xCount = UBound(xArr)
            If xCount > 0 Then
                For I = 0 To xCount - 1
                    xCell.Copy (I)
                    Sheets("Piece list").Activate
                    Range("E1").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                 Next
'                xArr2 = Split(xCell.Value, xLnum)
'                xCount2 = UBound(xArr2)
'            If xCount2 > 0 Then
'                xStrTmp = ""
'                For T = 0 To xCount2 - 1
'                    xStrTmp = xStrTmp & xArr2(T)
'
'                    xStrTmp = xStrTmp & xLStr
'                Next
            End If
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Here is my list of letters and numbers separated with "-" and commas

[image]

[Here is where I would like to put them sorted into the right column and by number in descending order

[image]

Here are my sheets

[image]

Comment: Code should be text and not a photo.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry I am fairly new to this website and how to post

Comment: Feel free to [edit] the post to include the code as text.

Comment: @ScottCraner after some minutes of confusion, its done!

Comment: Wonder why you want to pick a particular three-letter code. If your output list has all the codes listed in Row1 as headers, why not just list the entire data source split into the designated columns?  Pretty easy to do with either VBA or Power Query.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the three-letter and number code is manually inputted by me, so id like it to be listed each time so i dont have to search for the last FTA or WPA or SWA etc. as the numbers are in order.

Comment: Seems to me that you could create the table including all of the codes sorted and the numbers sorted descending. Then, if you need to determine the most recent code used; just use `HLOOKUP` (with your three letter code as the variable) against that table checking the 2nd row, which would be the most recent previously used.  When you enter the new code-number; update the table.

Comment: Also, why not just a routine that returns the next available number sequence for a particular three-letter text code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the strings into separate items. Then split the items into parts such that each item becomes a row with 3 columns e.g. ABC-123,ABC,123. Sort the data by columns 2 and 3 and then tabulate by column 1 onto a results sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, ar1 As Variant, ar2 As Variant
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim s As String, prev As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' data in col A
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets(2) ' temp sheet
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(3) ' output

    ' scan sheet 1, seperate and output to sheet 2
    i = 1
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 1 To iLastRow
        s = ws.Cells(r, 1)
        s = replace(s," ","") ' remove any spaces
        If Len(s) > 0 Then
            ar1 = Split(s, ",")
            For n = 0 To UBound(ar1)
               ar2 = Split(ar1(n), "-")
               wsData.Cells(i, 1) = ar1(n)
               wsData.Cells(i, 2) = ar2(0)
               wsData.Cells(i, 3) = ar2(1)
               i = i + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    iLastRow = i - 1
    
    ' sort on sheet 2
    With wsData.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & iLastRow)
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & iLastRow)
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C" & iLastRow)
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' tabulate onto sheet 3
    c = 0
    r = 0
    prev = ""
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        s = wsData.Cells(i, 2) 'abc
        If s <> prev Then
            ' start new column
            c = c + 1
            wsOut.Cells(1, c) = s
            wsOut.Cells(2, c) = wsData.Cells(i, 1)
            r = 3
        Else
            wsOut.Cells(r, c) = wsData.Cells(i, 1)
            r = r + 1
        End If
        prev = s
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what a temp is? I cannot find any info on google about it. Also does this code work if my data to be sorted is not in column A and does not start in row 1? Also my sheet 1 has other data like dates and such on it.

Comment: @josh temp is short for temporary - a sheet used to sort the data between the input on sheet 1 and the result on sheet 3, it can be hidden. `For r = 1 To iLastRow` scans from row 1 so change the 1 to start row. `s = ws.Cells(r, 1)` takes data from column "A" so change the 1 to to column you want. If you sheet 1 has more data update your question with a sample image.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly thank you. The one thing that is off is that i get two columns for some FTA's and CLA's.

Comment: @josh Clean up the strings removing hidden spaces by adding the line `s = replace(s," ","")` after `s = ws.Cells(r, 1)` in the first loop. Or use `s = trim(ws.Cells(r, 2))`

Comment: This cleaned it all up thank you for all your help and effort!!